# What is the term for diagonal bars which are making rectangular frame more rigid?

Tags: terminology, architecture, wood

For example in yellow:

[image]

if all bars were rectangular, the entige frame would tend to skew. To prevent this, these diagonal bars are mounted.

What is the term for them?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Braces. They come in a variety of shapes.

K frames, X frames, eccentric frames, etc.

.

[image]

.

[image: three different types]

.

.

Answer (score 4):

The generic term is **Bracing**.

You will often find it further qualified as **Cross Bracing**, **Diagonal Bracing** or **Triangular Bracing**, depending on the whim of the person doing it.

Answer (score 2):

One common name is **shear ties**.

Answer (score 2):

Another common term, used in many trades, is bracing, such as diagonal bracing.

Answer (score 0):

A term I recall from undergraduate Mechanics classes is Truss https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truss

Comment: A truss describes the whole assembly of beams and braces, but doesn't specifically describe the diagonal elements that provide rigidity. The addition of the diagonal braces could turn box framing into a truss, but they're not trusses themselves.